# lru_cache not leveraging cache with same input but passed in different ways

Tags: python

The problem is related to lru_cache, when I try to pass the same argument to the same cached function but in a different manner, the lru_cache will not be able to leverage cache. I would like to know if there is a better implementation that tackle the problem.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def fn(x,y):
    print('no cache')
    return 1

fn(1,1)
>>>>no cache

fn(x=1,1)
>>>>no cache

fn(x=1,y=1)
>>>>no cache
```

Comment: what's the version of python you use?

Comment: I am using python 3.6

Comment: looking at the [source code for lru_cache](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/functools.py#L427), there's a nice explanation of why they wrote it that way.  just looking through the code, it seems like they didn't want to assume anything about positional and kwd args about the underlying function.

Comment: @e.s. thanks for the findings, having kwarg sorted would solve fn(x=1,y=1) vs fn(y=1,x=1). The next step is to solve fn(1,y=1) vs fn(1,1).

Answer (score 0):

**tldr;** Looking at the [lru_cache source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/functools.py#L427), it doesn't do what you want because it would sacrifice speed and reliability for a very very limited use-case. (as an aside, it is worth reading through the source code to see all the nice optimizations they made.)

**long-winded response:** specifically, look at `_make_key` and how it is built for speed.
The purpose of the function is to take the arguments and keyword arguments you've passed in and make them into a unique key as quickly and reliably as possible.  Since the cache is being stored in a dictionary, it further optimizes this by making the keys a special object that hashes very efficiently for even faster lookup in the dictionary. All this makes the lru_cache really efficient and ensures it incurs an absolute minimum of overhead.

If you have a function like

```
def my_function(x, y=1, z=3):
    return x + (y*2) + (z**2)
```

if you call `my_function(1, 2)`, it looks up `args=(1, 2)` in the cache. It doesn't have to know that `1` is bound to `x` and `2` is bound to `y`. If you call `my_function(2, z=1)` it cannot assume that z is the next positional argument (which it isn't) because the cache is ignorant of the actual function signature. It will look up the cache key of `args=(2,), kwargs={'z': 1}`.

Imagine if the cache had to "know" the signature of each function. In this case it would have to know that all of these evaluate equal:

- `args=(5, 1, 3)` # currently stored in the cache as `_HashedSeq((5, 1, 3))`
- `args=(5,), kwargs={'z': 3}` # currently stored as `_HashedSeq((5, kwd_mard, ('z', 3)))`
- `args=(5,), kwargs={'y': 1}`
- `args=(), kwargs={'z': 3, 'y': 1, 'x': 5}`

This would be opening up a terrible can of worms that would involve using `inspect` to get the signature and tons of extra overhead and evaluating each kind of signature to see if it equaled one already in the cache.  Considering the efforts that the authors made to streamline this function, it would make lru_cache stop being good at what it's supposed to do, which is quickly and efficiently call up answers that were already computed.

Answer (score 0):

[Ring](https://pypi.org/project/ring/) resolve the key regardless of the order of keys provided. As commented in other answers, it is slower than `lru_cache`. If you are interested in the implementation, it merges positional and keywords arguments with a loop. See: https://github.com/youknowone/ring/blob/0.7.3/ring/callable.py#L23

```py
import ring

@ring.lru(maxsize=32)
def fn(x,y):
    print('no cache')
    return 1

fn(1,1)
>>>>no cache

fn(1,y=1)

fn(x=1,y=1)
```